# How to unbuffer stdout when piping commands in cmd.exe under Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, buffer

Given the following:

```
C:\>perl -E " say STDOUT 111; say STDERR 222; say STDOUT 333; "
111
222
333

C:\>perl -E " say STDOUT 111; say STDERR 222; say STDOUT 333; " | cat
222
111
333
```

The order of the output is not preserved when piping commands, due to stdout being buffered and stderr being unbuffered. How can stdout reliably be unbuffered so that the order will be preserved when piping commands?

I've searched all over trying to find solutions, I've tried scripts like `unbuffer` from the `expect` package in cygwin and Linux, but that only works within Cygwin (outside of it, in naked cmd.exe land, the order is still wrong, stderr still comes earlier than expected.) Same with `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ...`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem's not really buffering, but redirection: the `stdout` texts are delayed by being piped to `cat`, whereas those to `stderr` are written direct to the terminal as they are created. The easiest solution would be to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` before piping, as in `... 2>&1 | cat`. There is no way to ensure that running `cat` will interrupt the execution of `perl`.

Comment: @AFH Thanks, but I've tried that already too but still ends up out of order: `C:\>perl -E " say STDOUT 111; say STDERR 222; say STDOUT 333; " 2>&1 | cat` => `222 111 333`

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that: without `perl` on Windows, it's not that easy to test. I guess it's because both output streams are buffered, and output is generated only when both are closed, in which case the ordering depends on the order of file closure. In a C program you can set the output streams to be unbuffered, or program `fflush` after each `fputs`, but I don't know if this is possible in `perl` - maybe call a C function to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Perl's default I/O layers buffer, and don't use `stdio` to do so by default, which is why `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` (which modify the default `stdio` buffering) don't work.

Perl provides its own way to control the I/O layers used though: The `PERLIO` environment variable. Per [the `man perlrun` docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), it should be possible to run `set PERLIO=:unix` before running the command, or for raw native Windows handle based I/O, which may still be experimental/buggy, `set PERLIO=:win32`. Either one should bypass the normal buffering behavior by going straight to the raw system calls.

Assuming `cat` itself is unbuffered (I believe it uses raw reads and writes without buffering, so it should be), this still doesn't guarantee the behavior you want though. Perl could send the data to `cat` immediately, but unless `cat` manages to read it in and write it back out faster than Perl can move to the next line and print to `STDERR`, you'd still see the `STDERR` output first. In local tests (on Linux, but it should be pretty similar) with `PERLIO=:unix`, piping to `cat`, I saw the following outputs:

```
222111

333
```

then:

```
222
111
333
```

then:

```
111222

333
```

then (twice in a row):

```
111
222
333
```

Point is, even with buffering out of the equation, the piping introduces race conditions due to the process level parallelism. The only way around that is to make sure both streams go to `cat`:

```
perl -E "say STDOUT 111; say STDERR 222; say STDOUT 333;" 2>&1 | cat
```

consistently outputs:

```
111
222
333
```

because all the data is sent to `cat` immediately before the next `print` executes. The only other way to get (mostly) reliable ordering is to sleep between prints (allowing `cat` to win the race with `perl`).